# cat /proc/filesystems does not list vfat

Tags: filesystem, sd-card, fat32, proc

I'm trying to read an SD card formatted with a FAT32 filesystem. It can be read in windows, but not in Ubuntu.

When I tried `cat /proc/filesystems`, this was the output:

```
> cat /proc/filesystems 
nodev   sysfs
nodev   rootfs
nodev   bdev
nodev   proc
nodev   cgroup
nodev   cpuset
nodev   tmpfs
nodev   devtmpfs
nodev   debugfs
nodev   securityfs>
nodev   sockfs
nodev   pipefs
nodev   anon_inodefs
nodev   devpts
        ext3
        ext4
nodev   ramfs
nodev   hugetlbfs
nodev   ecryptfs
        fuseblk
nodev   fuse
nodev   fusectl
nodev   pstore
nodev   mqueue
nodev   binfmt_misc
```

I found that vfat was not listed.  Can someone tell me how this can be changed?

Comment: `/proc/filesystems` will only show you the filesystems built into the kernel or those modules that are loaded, but *not* those that can be loaded *as modules.*

Try this instead:
`grep VFAT /boot/config-$(uname -r)`

And if the result is `CONFIG_VFAT_FS=m`, then VFAT is indeed available. Just manually mount the card.

It would be almost impossible for a stock kernel to not support VFAT, built-in or as a module :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a line `vfat` to `/etc/filesystems` and make sure the file end with a line just containing a `*` (create the file if it doesn't exist).